Angular apps loaded from aspx page adds extra slash and doubles URL on server
I'm encountering an issue where an Angular 16 app, loaded in ASPX page (default.aspx), is adding an extra slash on the dev machine and on server, it is doubling the URL.
I have added base url in the default.aspx page.
<body>
<base href="/folder1/projectname/Default.aspx" />
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

When I load the below url
https://serverpath/projectname/Default.aspx?param=222001

After loaded the URL return with extra slash.
https://serverpath/projectname/Default.aspx/?param=222001

Below the routing screen shot:

